# Checkbox needing to click twice in the card but only once on the checkbox itself

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on a recyclerView that will list a few itens that have a checkbox on each item.
On the checkbox itself, it only needs one click to check, but on the card (only for the first time), it needs two clicks on the card to check, after that, it recognizes each click separetely.

**Basically, I need two click two times for the first time in each item in the card to the checkbox be checked for the first time and then, it works normally.**

Tried focusableInTouchMode in true and false and the problem occurred anyways.

Sorry for the typo mistakes here.

My item XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/half_default_size"
    android:background="@drawable/team_member_rounded">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/half_default_size"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/members_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/default_size"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cv_member"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/cl_checkbox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_member"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_member_name"
                        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_default_size"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/checkbox_member"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        tools:text="C012345 TESTE" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>`

</layout>
```

My setOnClickListener:

```
holder.checkBox.setChecked(membersSelected.contains(agent));
holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    if (membersSelected.contains(agent)) {
        membersSelected.remove(agent);
    } else {
        membersSelected.add(agent);
    }
});

holder.cardMember.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(membersSelected.contains(agent));
    if (membersSelected.contains(agent)) {
        membersSelected.remove(agent);
    } else {
        membersSelected.add(agent);
    }
});

holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(membersSelected.contains(agent));
    if (membersSelected.contains(agent)) {
        membersSelected.remove(agent);
    } else {
        membersSelected.add(agent);
    }
});

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    holder.checkBox.performClick();
    holder.cardMember.performClick();
    holder.cardView.performClick();
});
```

Tried using focusableInTouchMode="false" and "true", tried adding every component in the item to be clickable and so on.

Comment: Your problem is unclear. Please clarify your problem simply by specifying what you expect and what you get.

Comment: @Kozmotronik I've edited the description to resume the problem and make more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.

First of all, I've noticed that I was using a ConstraintLayout inside a CardView **inside** in another ConstraintLayout that was inside in another CardView. First of all, I've removed 2 of them from the XML and included            `android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground">` in the ConstraintLayout, makint it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/half_default_size"
    android:background="@drawable/team_member_rounded">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_member"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/half_default_size"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/members_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/default_size"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_member"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_member_name"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_default_size"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/checkbox_member"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="C012345 TESTE" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</layout>
```

And for the the adapter, on the onBindViewHolder, I changed to:

```
holder.checkBox.setChecked(membersSelected.contains(agent));
        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (membersSelected.contains(agent)) {
                membersSelected.remove(agent);
            } else {
                membersSelected.add(agent);
            }
        });

        holder.cardMember.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            holder.checkBox.performClick();
        });
```

With this, the cardView recognize the first click and check the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Create model named members

```
public class Member{
    int clickCount = 0;
    String members;
//getters and setters
}
```

then add all members to the list of member

```
List<Member> memberList = new ArrayList();

for(int i=0;i<members.size();i++){
    Member member = new Member();
    member.setMember(members.get(i));
    memberList.add(member);
}
```

then pass the memberList to the adapter and increment the value of clickCount on click of the cardview, and on 2 clickCount you can set checkBox as checked
then